# error in reading worker properties configuration failed in Apache load balancer

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing, mod-jk

I am using Apache load balancer apache2.25 .

Trying to balance 2 tomcat instances and configured workers.properties accordingly.

Below is my workers.properties.

```
worker.list=balancer

worker.worker1.port=8080

worker.worker1.host=15.0.3.169

worker.worker1.type=ajp13

worker.worker1.lbfactor=1

worker.worker2.port=8181

worker.worker2.host=15.0.3.169

worker.worker2.type=ajp13

worker.worker2.lbfactor=1

worker.balancer.type=lb

worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2

worker.balancer.method=B

worker.balancer. sticky_session =True**
```

When I am Trying to start achache load balancer, It is throwing following error..

```
Error in reading worker properties from 'C:/Apache2.25/conf/workers.properties'
Configuration Failed
```

Kindly, Help me out to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you have configured httpd.conf?

If you are including mod_jk.conf, then comment out include section and use the following:

---

```
# C:/.../apache-tomcat/conf/auto/mod_jk.conf
# Load mod_jk
#
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogLevel debug
JkLogLevel warn
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkMount / loadbalancer
JkMount /* loadbalancer
```